# Have troubles with writing a procedure on PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, create-table

So, basically, I need to create a procedure that takes names of two tables as parameter, then creates a new table, in which foreign keys are connected with primary keys of tables from parameters.

What do I need: I need this procedure to take two already existing in DB tables, find those columns that are constrained with primary key, create a table (that's why I use `execute immediate`, of cource) that references with its fks on primary keys of my two tables with those column names as datatypes for newly created columns, since we don't know what was the datatype for pk columns of parameter tables. As a result, this procedure should write a name of the table that was created or show error that was occured (but not ORA).

The main trouble is in creating a table part, I don't know how to put those column names in (I wish it was just one), I was told that I could use substring, but not sure how in that situation I can do this, since I don't know the length of the column's name, and I'm not sure if the info about my columns is full without binds, where should I use it.

Editing what was written previously, that's full text of my procedure.

```
create or replace procedure table_creation (table_a varchar2, table_b varchar2) 
is 
l_cnt_a number;
l_cnt_b number;
l_str_a varchar2 (32767); 
l_str_b varchar2 (32767); 
l_pk_a varchar2 (32767); 
l_pk_b varchar2 (32767); 
err1 exception;
err2 exception; 
sql_text varchar2 (32767); 
begin 
SELECT count(1), 
max(cols.constraint_name), listing(cols.column_name || '_1' ',') 
INTO l_cnt_a, l_str_a, l_pk_a 
FROM all_constraints cons 
INNER JOIN all_cons_columns cols ON cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
WHERE cons.table_name = table_a 
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'; 
IF l_cnt = 0 then 
RAISE err; 
END IF;

SELECT count(1), 
max(cols.constraint_name), listing(cols.column_name || '_2' ',') 
INTO l_cnt_b, l_str_b, l_pk_b
FROM all_constraints cons 
INNER JOIN all_cons_columns cols ON cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
WHERE cons.table_name = table_b
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'; 
IF l_cnt = 0 then 
RAISE err; 
END IF;

sql_text := 
'create or replace table table_c ('
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'for i in 1..l_cnt_a loop'
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'column_for_a_i a_i_column%TYPE, '
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'end loop'
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'for i in 1..l_cnt_b loop'
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'column_for_b_i b_i_column%TYPE, '
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'end loop'
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'constraint fk_a' 
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'foreign key (column_for_a_i) '
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'references table_a(l_pk_a), '
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'constraint fk_b' 
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'foreign key (column_for_b_i) '
|| CHR(10) 
|| 'references table_b(l_pk_b), '
|| CHR(10) 
|| ') ';

execute immediate sql_text;
dbms_output.put_line('done');
exception
when err1 then 
dbms_output.put_line('first table');
when err2 then 
dbms_output.put_line('second table');
end table_creation;
```

I'm sorry if it's a bit unreadable, I'm still learning( and hope that now the problem is more understandable, if not - I'll try again XD

Comment: `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` are going to give the same output so it is unclear what you are trying to achieve with that code.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: a **complete** example of your procedure (not an out-of-context fragment of the procedure); an English explanation of the problem you are trying to solve (expanding your first paragraph to explain why you need dynamic SQL to generate the DDL statement and what the problem with foreign keys is; not the XY-problem in your final paragraph); the issues/errors with the procedure; and the expected output from the procedure.

Comment: To debug this , commented the execute immediate and add dbms_output.put_line(sql_text); in place of the same. This will print the string command that will be executed. You can then change the logic to change the string to the one that you need to be executed. Once you are able to create the string you remove the dbms_output.put_line and replace it with execute immediate. what is happening is your sql text that is created has syntax errors that is why the table is not get tinglass created. Eg. You used create or replace table, it should be CREATE TABLE table_name.

Comment: There is no 'create or replace table' : (create | drop | alter ) table TABLE_NAME and "create table TABLE_NAME if not exists" appeared only in 23c. 
'for i in 1..l_cnt_a loop' is PL/SQL, execute immediate expect a SQL statement...

Comment: Thanks! I deleted 'or replace' and tried to concentrate on smaller task, which is just create table with foreign key for one column primary key in each of parameter tables, but still there's a ORA error, for now it's ORA-00911... I think it's because of %TYPE, yet I have no idea for now how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code generates sql_text as a combination of DDL and PL/SQL - that will not work. You should create dynamic code that is either DDL or PL/SQL. I don't realy understand the quuestion but I'll try to propose solution for a part of it.
Quote: ***"The main trouble is in creating a table part, I don't know how to put those column names in"*** end quote.
You can generate the complete CREATE TABLE command using something like below.

```sql
Select  'CREATE TABLE ' || CHR(10) || CHR(9) || 
    'NEW_TABLE' || CHR(10) || CHR(9) || '(' || 
        SubStr(COL_DESC, 3, Length(COL_DESC) - 4) || CHR(10) || CHR(9) || 
    ')' "CREATE_TABLE_DDL"
From    (   Select   LISTAGG(CHR(10) || CHR(9) || CHR(9) || 
                Case When TABLE_NAME = 'A_TBL_1' Then COLUMN_NAME || '_FROM_T1 ' 
                Else COLUMN_NAME || '_FROM_T2 ' 
                End || 
                Case When DATA_TYPE = 'DATE' Then DATA_TYPE || ', '
                Else DATA_TYPE || '(' || CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'NUMBER' 
                                              THEN To_Char(DATA_PRECISION) || ', ' || To_Char(DATA_SCALE) 
                                         ELSE To_Char(DATA_LENGTH) 
                                         END 
                                       || ')' || Case When NULLABLE = 'N' Then ' NOT NULL' End || ', '
                End
              ) WITHIN GROUP (Order By TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID) "COL_DESC"
      From all_tab_columns 
      Where TABLE_NAME IN('A_TBL_1', 'A_TBL_2')
      Order By TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID
    )
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--
--  CREATE_TABLE_DDL
--  ---------------------------------------------------
--  CREATE TABLE 
--      NEW_TABLE 
--      (   ID_FROM_T1 NUMBER(3, 0) NOT NULL,   
--          T2_ID_FROM_T1 VARCHAR2(20),   
--          SOME_COLUMN_FROM_T1 DATE,   
--          ID_FROM_T2 VARCHAR2(3, 0) NOT NULL,   
--          T1_ID_FROM_T2 NUMBER(22),   
--          SOME_OTHER_COLUMN_FROM_T2 VARCHAR2(20)  
--      )
```

NOTE: I used 2 dummy tables. You can use your procedure's parameters instead and  store the result into your sql_text variable. Similarily you can generate other DDL statements too.
Dummy tables used:

```sql
Desc A_TBL_1;
Name        Null?    Type         
----------- -------- ------------ 
ID          NOT NULL NUMBER(3)    
T2_ID                VARCHAR2(20) 
SOME_COLUMN          DATE        

Desc A_TBL_2;
Name              Null?    Type         
----------------- -------- ------------ 
ID                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
T1_ID                      NUMBER(3)    
SOME_OTHER_COLUMN          VARCHAR2(20)
```

Comment: Oh wow, that looks cool, thank you! I've managed to create a procedure for simple primary keys, based on just one column, I'll add this solution below later, that kinda worked for me, yet there still are few ORA errors I'm trying to deal with, however, it works in most of the cases and I'm happy with that. As for the code you've sent — I'll try to utilize it, hope that'll be good.

Comment: @Asparagusista I'm sure you can adjust the code to do the job. Same way you can generate other DDLs. Feel free to do whatever needed with this code. Use the similar approach for rest.. Just play a little with inner query, see the result and handle it with outer query. Glad you like it.